# Fast way to switch to next/previous directory in command line

Tags: command-line, zsh, software-rec

Consider a directory containing sub directories `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3` etc.

Now consider the case that I am in `sub3` and want to switch to `sub4`, I do something like `cd ../sub4`. However I want something like `next` to switch to the "next" directory and `prev` to switch to the previous one, where the order should be alphanumerical (and optionally by `mtime`). Maybe this could be also be bound to a convenient keyboard shortcut.

For example using `next` when you are in `sub3` brings you to `sub4` etc.

Is there any build in functionality of `zsh` or any tool to get something like this out ouf the box?

Comment: Should using `next` when in `sub4` wrap and go to `sub1`?

Comment: Hm. I think it would be better it goes to the first directory when you are in the last one. So yes.

Comment: Very similar (although not a duplicate since OP asks for a Zsh builtin): [How can I cd to the previous/next sibling directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41214)

Comment: @student Checkpoint/Spawnpoint/Teleport-Like command in Linux:   pushd and popd?     (:D)  It works multiple times I think, too..

Comment: (Aside: you can do `cd 3 4` and zsh will replace `3` with `4` in the current path and `cd` there. e.g., `/some/where/sub3` will become `/some/where/sub4`, `/else/where/3sub/foo` will become `/else/where/4sub/foo`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `cdprev` and `cdnext` functions like:

```
cdnext cdprev() {
  local dirs i
  dirs=(${PWD%/*}/*(nN-/))

  if (($#dirs <= 1)); then
    print -ru2 No other dir in $PWD:h
    return 1
  fi

  i=$dirs[(Ie)$PWD]
  if [[ $0 = cdnext ]]; then
    ((i++))
  else
    ((i--))
  fi
  ((i <= $#dirs)) || i=1
  ((i >= 1 ))     || i=-1

  print -ru2 $0: ${(D)dirs[i]}
  cd $dirs[i]
}
```